# cross reference 2 fields in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm developing an app in PHP (actually codeigniter)+MYSQL...I'll try to put it as simple as I can

I'm doing a select on my product table so I get the following:

```
color        size        quantity
red          s           2
red          m           3
red          l           4
red          xl          1
blue         s           1
blue         m           0
blue         l           0
blue         xl          1
```

I need to display the result this way

```
color        s        m        l        xl
red          2        3        4        1
blue         1        0        0        1
```

Any ideas??? SQL or PHP will be ok...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are fine with hardcoding the sizes in the `SELECT` clause then you can use the following query:

```
SELECT color,
       SUM(IF(size = 's', quantity, 0)) s,
       SUM(IF(size = 'm', quantity, 0)) m,
       SUM(IF(size = 'l', quantity, 0)) l,
       SUM(IF(size = 'xl', quantity, 0)) xl
FROM products
GROUP BY color
```

Otherwise you could implement it in PHP using a loop (such as [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach)).

Comment: that would be OK if all the products had S M L and XL sizes. The problem is that some products have 6 sizes, and sometimes only 1 size.. I'm thinking a PHP script should do the trick.

Comment: @Carlos Arenas: Please note that this solution also works if not all products have S M L and XL. It will just display "0" for those that are missing a size. So, as long as you put all sizes in the SELECT clause you will get the result as it was expected. Still, if you can't hardcode the size names (as I said in the reply) you should go for the PHP processing.

Comment: ok, I think I got it.... First I'll do a SELECT to get all the sizes according to the product, for example S M L XL XXL XXXL. Next I'll use PHP to edit a new query just like yours, HARDCODING the sizes from the first select whit a simple FOREACH... I'll try it  next thursday when I get to the office and post the results here.

Answer (score 1):

Admittedly, after seeing the other posts doing this directly from the database with their grouping, this method seems pretty lame.  You can, however, use PHP to format the data by storing each color in its own array and then iterating over it from there:

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

$q = 'SELECT * FROM product ORDER BY color';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $q);

$color_array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $color = $row['color'];
    $size = $row['size'];
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];

    $color_array[$color][$size] = $quantity;

}

foreach ($color_array AS $color_key => $color_item) {

    print $color_key."\t".$color_item['s']."\t".$color_item['m']."\t".$color_item['l']."\t".$color_item['xl']."\n";

}
```

EDIT:

I saw in your comment that you may have between 1 and 6 sizes.  My original code would not have really worked for that, so I modified it a little to read the sizes from an array and then print them out if they are found in the database.

```
<?php

$link = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'database');

$size_array = array('s', 'm', 'l', 'xl', 'xxl', 'xxxl');

$q = 'SELECT * FROM colors ORDER BY color';
$result = mysqli_query($link, $q);

$color_array = array();

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $color = $row['color'];
    $size = $row['size'];
    $quantity = $row['quantity'];

    $color_array[$color][$size] = $quantity;

}

foreach ($color_array AS $color_key => $color_item) {


    print "\n".$color_key."\t";

    foreach ($size_array AS $size) {
        print isset($color_item[$size]) ? $color_item[$size]."\t" : "\t";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution in sql

**UPDATED:**
1. test using more example data
2. Change the cursor's SQL query to handle the total quantity for each size.

Example Data: (this data is in the temporary table @temp)

```
color                size  quantity
-------------------- ----- -----------
red                  s     2
red                  m     3
red                  l     4
red                  xl    1
Yellow               s     5
blue                 s     1
blue                 m     0
blue                 l     0
blue                 xl    1
red                  xl    1
blue                 xl    1
Green                xl    1
```

SQL Query:

```
declare @temp2 table
(
  color nvarchar(20),
  s int,
  m int,
  l int,
  xl int
)


declare @color nvarchar(20), @size nvarchar(5), @quantity int

declare myCursor Cursor for
select color,size,sum(quantity) from @temp group by color,size order by color, size

Open myCursor
Fetch next from myCursor into @color, @size, @quantity

while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin



        if @size = 's'  
         begin
            update @temp2 set s = @quantity where color = @color
            if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
             insert into @temp2 (color, s) values (@color, @quantity)
         end
        if @size = 'm'
         begin  
            update @temp2 set m = @quantity where color = @color
            if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                insert into @temp2 (color, m) values (@color, @quantity)
         end
        if @size = 'l'
         begin  
            update @temp2 set l = @quantity where color = @color
            if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
                insert into @temp2 (color, l) values (@color, @quantity)
         end
        if @size = 'xl' 
         begin 
            update @temp2 set xl = @quantity where color = @color
            if @@ROWCOUNT = 0
             insert into @temp2 (color, xl) values (@color, @quantity)
         end




    Fetch next from myCursor into @color, @size, @quantity
end

close myCursor
Deallocate myCursor

select color, isnull(s,0) as s, isnull(m,0) as m, isnull(l,0) as l,isnull(xl,0) as xl from @temp2
```

RESULT DATA:

```
color                s           m           l           xl
-------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
blue                 1           0           0           2
Green                0           0           0           1
red                  2           3           4           2
Yellow               5           0           0           0
```

Answer (score 0):

So, Thanks to @Razvan, i did it this way...

```
    $query_size=$this->db->query("SELECT size FROM sizes inner join product on sizes.product_type=product.type where product.id='$product_id'");
    $sql="SELECT color";
    foreach($query_size->result() as $size){
        $sql=$sql . ", SUM(IF(size = '$size->size', quantity, 0)) as $size->size";
    }
    $sql=$sql . " FROM products WHERE id='$product_id' GROUP BY color";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
```